# Load multiple views with data in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: codeigniter

I want to load multiple views with data on it and then it download its content instantly and close it, after user click a button and select multiple checkboxes(in a view). Below is my code (controller) using CodeIgniter 4, but I just get one view (and download it):

```
public function MorePreview()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['btnDownload'])) {
            if (!empty($this->request->getVar('ck_Download_TA'))) {
                        
                $download = $this->request->getVar('ck_Download_TA');
               // dd($download);
                foreach ($download as $kode) {
                    $NamafileTandaTangan = '';
                    $tt = $this->rhModel->getViewTandaTangan($kode);
                    if (count($tt) > 0) { 
                        $NamafileTandaTangan = $tt[0]['lokasi'];
                        $NamafileTandaTangan = substr($NamafileTandaTangan, 12);
                    } 
                    $sertifikat = $this->sertModel = new sertModel();
                    $srt = $sertifikat->getSrtWithKode($kode);
                    $bhs = $this->bhsModel->getBhsWithKode($kode);
                    $pengalaman = $this->ModelPengalaman->getPengalaman($kode);
                    $pengalaman_nq = $this->expNonQModel = new expNonQModel();
                    $experiences = $pengalaman_nq->CariSemuaKodeTA($kode); 
                    $pendidikan = $this->eduModel->getEduWithKode($kode);
                    
                    $ta = $this->rhModel->getCVwithKode($kode);
                
                    //  Mencari tanggal lahir, untuk dikonversi dari angka menjadi nama bulan 
                    $tanggal = '';
                    $tgl = isset($ta['tgl']) ? $ta['tgl'] : '';
                    if ($tgl != '0000-00-00' && $tgl != null && $tgl != '') {
                        $tgl = substr($ta['tgl'], 8, 2);
                        $bln = substr($ta['tgl'], 5, 2);
                        //  Memanggil helper 
                        helper('custom_helper'); // Loading single helper
                        //  Memanggil fungsi NamaBulan() untuk mencetak nama-nama bulan
                        $bulan = NamaBulan($bln);
                        $thn = substr($ta['tgl'], 0, 4);
                        $tanggal = $tgl . " " . $bulan . " " . $thn;
                    }
                    //  Mencari status pegawai
                    $status = isset($ta['status_pgw']) ? $ta['status_pgw'] : '';

                    $data = [
                        'ta' => $ta,
                        'status' => $status,
                        'tt' => $NamafileTandaTangan,
                        'tgl_lahir' => $tanggal,
                        'srt' => $srt,
                        'bhs' => $bhs,
                        'pendidikan' => $pendidikan,
                        'pengalaman' => $pengalaman,
                        'pengalamanNonQ' => $experiences
                    ];
                    //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0npImrPi3Jk&list=PL79xP87McblnMZG-F1hnRLuMgM5C95nMG&index=10&ab_channel=GoPHP
                    echo view('rh/download_rh', $data);
                    echo  "<script type='text/javascript'>";
                    echo "window.close();";
                    echo "</script>";
                }
            }
        }
         
    }
```

The problem is I can't get iteration through for loops, is there anybody could help me ?

Comment: please debug with `echo('<pre>'); print_r($download); die();`: what is the output?

Comment: It's still the same, print curriculum vitae just one person, it should print more than one person if the foreach loop can iterate.

Comment: so how does `$this->request->getVar('ck_Download_TA')` look like? if it returns only the data for one person, then there is only one iteration...

Comment: It's a checkbox inside a table (in a view) that show a list of persons (expert) data , and when user clicks more than one checkbox, then click a button (on top of list), it will call a procedure (<form action="/rh/download" method="GET">) in controller(above), and the controller will check whether there are checkboxes that have been checked, and then the controller will call another view that download (via html2pdf library) multiple curriculum vitae.

Comment: This is the code of checkboxes inside a table (foreach loop) that can be choosen by the user to download multiple person curriculum vitae :   <td style="width:10%">
<input type="checkbox" name="ck_Download_TA[]" value="<?= $v['kode_ta'] ?>"></td>

Comment: and this is the JavaScript code inside download_rh (view) that download the view (html) :   window.onload = function() {
            var element = document.getElementById('element-to-print');
            var namanya = document.getElementById('namanya').value; 
            html2pdf().from(element).save(namanya + '.pdf');
        };

Comment: So in your iteration you are closing each view by `window.close();` which is why maybe you are just getting one view

Comment: I'm sorry cause I didn't work (as a programmer) for the company anymore (resign), but thanks anyway,.... maybe you're right.